# Some method in child element after componentDidMount in parrent element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use react.js and i have one question. I have two component: Child and Parrent.

```
import React, { Component, Children, cloneElement } from 'react'
import {render} from 'react-dom'

class Child extends Component {
    someMethod() {
        /* Some code... */
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        /* Some code... */
        console.log("Child component did mount!");
    }
    render() {
        return <span>Child</span>
    }
}

class Parent extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        /* Some code... */
        console.log("Parent component did mount!");
    }
    render() {
        let children = Children.map(this.props.children, (element, idx) => {
            return cloneElement(element, { ref: idx });
        });

        return (
            <div>
                {children}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const demo = (
    <Parent>
        <Child></Child>
    </Parent>
);

render(demo,document.querySelector('#demo'));
```

I need a method in child element (`someMethod` in code) which will be running after was run `componentDidMount` in parrent element. Thank's.
P.S. React and ReactDom version is 0.14.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. This is not very good, but it works.
I use `setTimeout(..., 0)`
In child element

```
componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(()=>{
        /* Some code which will be run after componentDidMount in parent */
    },0);
}
```